# multi theme flutter with GetX

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to have like 10 different themes in my app. but the problem is that Whenever I'm changing the theme, only parts of the app changes the theme. like app-bar or bottom-navigation. but some other parts of the app keeps it's original theme and wont change until I Restart the app.

here is my code.

```
  void changeTheme(final ThemeData themeData, final ThemeType themeType, final ThemeMode themeMode) async {
    Get.changeTheme(themeData);
    Get.changeThemeMode(themeMode);
    await Get.forceAppUpdate();
    setData("theme", themeType.toString());
    setData("themeMode", themeMode.toString());
  }
```

`ThemeData` is the different theme I made.
`ThemeType` is an enum I used to persist the theme is local storage.
`ThemeMode` is for changing the dark and light theme.

and here is my App:

```
class _AppState extends State<App> {
  @override
  Widget build(final BuildContext context) => GetMaterialApp(
        enableLog: false,
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        localizationsDelegates: const <LocalizationsDelegate<dynamic>>[
          GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
          S.delegate,
        ],
        theme: AppThemes.light,
        darkTheme: AppThemes.dark,
        themeMode: getThemeMode(),
        home: const MainPage(),
        builder: EasyLoading.init(),
      );

  ThemeData getTheme() {
    if (getData("theme") == ThemeType.light.toString()) return AppThemes.light;
    if (getData("theme") == ThemeType.dark.toString()) return AppThemes.dark;
    return AppThemes.light;
  }

  ThemeMode getThemeMode() {
    if (getData("themeMode") == ThemeMode.light.toString()) return ThemeMode.light;
    if (getData("themeMode") == ThemeMode.dark.toString()) return ThemeMode.dark;
    return ThemeMode.system;
  }
}
```

How can I change my theme dynamically with different colors at realtime?

Comment: In your main.dart are you using MaterialApp or GetMaterialApp widget and its theme property?